# Transform polymer (PolymerBootstrapTransformer) on polymer_snippet|web/index.html threw error: unexpected keyword: as

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-eclipse-plugin

I recently updated my Dart eclipse plugin to the current DEV release and now my application will not run. I get this error on attempt to run the index.html file of the application

```
--- 5:27:22 PM Starting pub serve : polymer_snippet ---
Loading source assets...
Loading polymer and sass transformers...
Serving polymer_snippet web on http://localhost:8080
Build error:
Transform polymer (PolymerBootstrapTransformer) on polymer_snippet|web/index.html threw error: unexpected keyword: as
package:polymer_expressions/parser.dart 159                 Parser._parsePrimary
package:polymer_expressions/parser.dart 138                 Parser._parseUnary
package:polymer_expressions/parser.dart 106                 Parser._parseBinary
package:polymer_expressions/parser.dart 80                  Parser._parsePrecedence
package:polymer_expressions/parser.dart 46                  Parser._parseExpression
package:polymer_expressions/parser.dart 32                  Parser.parse
package:polymer_expressions/parser.dart 15                  parse
package:polymer/src/build/polymer_smoke_generator.dart 526  _HtmlExtractor._addExpression
package:polymer/src/build/polymer_smoke_generator.dart 461  _HtmlExtractor.visitText
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 15                            TreeVisitor.visit
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 31                            TreeVisitor.visitChildren
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 37                            TreeVisitor.visitNodeFallback
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 46                            TreeVisitor.visitElement
package:polymer/src/build/polymer_smoke_generator.dart 450  _HtmlExtractor.visitElement
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 13                            TreeVisitor.visit
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 31                            TreeVisitor.visitChildren
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 37                            TreeVisitor.visitNodeFallback
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 46                            TreeVisitor.visitElement
package:polymer/src/build/polymer_smoke_generator.dart 450  _HtmlExtractor.visitElement
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 13                            TreeVisitor.visit
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 31                            TreeVisitor.visitChildren
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 37                            TreeVisitor.visitNodeFallback
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 46                            TreeVisitor.visitElement
package:polymer/src/build/polymer_smoke_generator.dart 450  _HtmlExtractor.visitElement
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 13                            TreeVisitor.visit
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 31                            TreeVisitor.visitChildren
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 37                            TreeVisitor.visitNodeFallback
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 46                            TreeVisitor.visitElement
package:polymer/src/build/polymer_smoke_generator.dart 450  _HtmlExtractor.visitElement
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 13                            TreeVisitor.visit
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 31                            TreeVisitor.visitChildren
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 37                            TreeVisitor.visitNodeFallback
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 46                            TreeVisitor.visitElement
package:polymer/src/build/polymer_smoke_generator.dart 450  _HtmlExtractor.visitElement
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 13                            TreeVisitor.visit
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 31                            TreeVisitor.visitChildren
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 37                            TreeVisitor.visitNodeFallback
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 46                            TreeVisitor.visitElement
package:polymer/src/build/polymer_smoke_generator.dart 450  _HtmlExtractor.visitElement
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 13                            TreeVisitor.visit
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 31                            TreeVisitor.visitChildren
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 37                            TreeVisitor.visitNodeFallback
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 46                            TreeVisitor.visitElement
package:polymer/src/build/polymer_smoke_generator.dart 447  _HtmlExtractor.visitElement
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 13                            TreeVisitor.visit
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 31                            TreeVisitor.visitChildren
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 37                            TreeVisitor.visitNodeFallback
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 46                            TreeVisitor.visitElement
package:polymer/src/build/polymer_smoke_generator.dart 450  _HtmlExtractor.visitElement
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 13                            TreeVisitor.visit
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 31                            TreeVisitor.visitChildren
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 37                            TreeVisitor.visitNodeFallback
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 46                            TreeVisitor.visitElement
package:polymer/src/build/polymer_smoke_generator.dart 450  _HtmlExtractor.visitElement
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 13                            TreeVisitor.visit
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 31                            TreeVisitor.visitChildren
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 37                            TreeVisitor.visitNodeFallback
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 46                            TreeVisitor.visitElement
package:polymer/src/build/polymer_smoke_generator.dart 450  _HtmlExtractor.visitElement
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 13                            TreeVisitor.visit
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 31                            TreeVisitor.visitChildren
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 37                            TreeVisitor.visitNodeFallback
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 39                            TreeVisitor.visitDocument
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 21                            TreeVisitor.visit
package:polymer/src/build/polymer_smoke_generator.dart 169  PolymerSmokeGenerator._extractUsesOfMirrors.<fn>
dart:async/zone.dart 1155                                   _RootZone.runUnary
dart:async/future_impl.dart 494                             _Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback
dart:async/future_impl.dart 577                             _Future._propagateToListeners
dart:async/future_impl.dart 358                             _Future._complete
dart:async/future.dart 364                                  Future.doWhile.<fn>
dart:async/zone.dart 1093                                   _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded
dart:async/zone.dart 1122                                   _RootZone.bindUnaryCallback.<fn>
dart:async/zone.dart 1155                                   _RootZone.runUnary
dart:async/future_impl.dart 494                             _Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback
dart:async/future_impl.dart 577                             _Future._propagateToListeners
dart:async/future_impl.dart 368                             _Future._completeWithValue
dart:async/future_impl.dart 422                             _Future._asyncComplete.<fn>
dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart 41                       _asyncRunCallbackLoop
dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart 48                       _asyncRunCallback
dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart 96                    _runPendingImmediateCallback
dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart 143                   _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage

package:polymer_expressions/parser.dart 159                 Parser._parsePrimary
package:polymer_expressions/parser.dart 138                 Parser._parseUnary
package:polymer_expressions/parser.dart 106                 Parser._parseBinary
package:polymer_expressions/parser.dart 80                  Parser._parsePrecedence
package:polymer_expressions/parser.dart 46                  Parser._parseExpression
package:polymer_expressions/parser.dart 32                  Parser.parse
package:polymer_expressions/parser.dart 15                  parse
package:polymer/src/build/polymer_smoke_generator.dart 526  _HtmlExtractor._addExpression
package:polymer/src/build/polymer_smoke_generator.dart 461  _HtmlExtractor.visitText
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 15                            TreeVisitor.visit
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 31                            TreeVisitor.visitChildren
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 37                            TreeVisitor.visitNodeFallback
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 46                            TreeVisitor.visitElement
package:polymer/src/build/polymer_smoke_generator.dart 450  _HtmlExtractor.visitElement
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 13                            TreeVisitor.visit
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 31                            TreeVisitor.visitChildren
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 37                            TreeVisitor.visitNodeFallback
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 46                            TreeVisitor.visitElement
package:polymer/src/build/polymer_smoke_generator.dart 450  _HtmlExtractor.visitElement
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 13                            TreeVisitor.visit
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 31                            TreeVisitor.visitChildren
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 37                            TreeVisitor.visitNodeFallback
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 46                            TreeVisitor.visitElement
package:polymer/src/build/polymer_smoke_generator.dart 450  _HtmlExtractor.visitElement
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 13                            TreeVisitor.visit
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 31                            TreeVisitor.visitChildren
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 37                            TreeVisitor.visitNodeFallback
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 46                            TreeVisitor.visitElement
package:polymer/src/build/polymer_smoke_generator.dart 450  _HtmlExtractor.visitElement
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 13                            TreeVisitor.visit
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 31                            TreeVisitor.visitChildren
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 37                            TreeVisitor.visitNodeFallback
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 46                            TreeVisitor.visitElement
package:polymer/src/build/polymer_smoke_generator.dart 450  _HtmlExtractor.visitElement
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 13                            TreeVisitor.visit
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 31                            TreeVisitor.visitChildren
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 37                            TreeVisitor.visitNodeFallback
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 46                            TreeVisitor.visitElement
package:polymer/src/build/polymer_smoke_generator.dart 450  _HtmlExtractor.visitElement
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 13                            TreeVisitor.visit
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 31                            TreeVisitor.visitChildren
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 37                            TreeVisitor.visitNodeFallback
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 46                            TreeVisitor.visitElement
package:polymer/src/build/polymer_smoke_generator.dart 447  _HtmlExtractor.visitElement
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 13                            TreeVisitor.visit
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 31                            TreeVisitor.visitChildren
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 37                            TreeVisitor.visitNodeFallback
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 46                            TreeVisitor.visitElement
package:polymer/src/build/polymer_smoke_generator.dart 450  _HtmlExtractor.visitElement
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 13                            TreeVisitor.visit
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 31                            TreeVisitor.visitChildren
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 37                            TreeVisitor.visitNodeFallback
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 46                            TreeVisitor.visitElement
package:polymer/src/build/polymer_smoke_generator.dart 450  _HtmlExtractor.visitElement
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 13                            TreeVisitor.visit
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 31                            TreeVisitor.visitChildren
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 37                            TreeVisitor.visitNodeFallback
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 46                            TreeVisitor.visitElement
package:polymer/src/build/polymer_smoke_generator.dart 450  _HtmlExtractor.visitElement
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 13                            TreeVisitor.visit
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 31                            TreeVisitor.visitChildren
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 37                            TreeVisitor.visitNodeFallback
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 39                            TreeVisitor.visitDocument
package:html/dom_parsing.dart 21                            TreeVisitor.visit
package:polymer/src/build/polymer_smoke_generator.dart 169  PolymerSmokeGenerator._extractUsesOfMirrors.<fn>
dart:isolate                                                _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage
Build completed with 1 errors.
[web] GET /index.html => Could not find asset polymer_snippet|web/index.html.
```

I have not seen such a stack trace before.

The index.html is present yet it cannot be found on execution.

I cannot find any 'unexpected' keyword mentioned above in line 6.

Thanks

Comment: Do you use `as` in any Polymer expression? You could try to run `pub build` to check if you get an error here as well and maybe more detailed information about the cause.

Comment: Or if you can post a link to your project we can diagnose it that way? It does sound like you have `as` in a Polymer Expression though, which isn't valid afaik.